# derivative of the integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am working on a few problems, just need some help to see if I'm working them correctly,

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;g(x)=\int_0^x(x-u)e^{u^2}du$$ find $g'(x),g''(x)$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\psi(x,y)=\int_1^xe^{ty}dt$$ find $\partial \psi/\partial x, \partial \psi/\partial y$

for the first, problem I get,

$$g'(x)=\int_0^x(1-u)e^{u^2}du$$
$$g''(x)=0$$

for the second problem I get,

$$\partial \psi/\partial x=0$$
$$\partial \psi/\partial y=\int_1^x te^{ty}dt$$

Please help me to know if I am thinking correctly on these, or what theorems I am lacking.  Many thanks

Comment: the results are incorrect - maybe you should show us some of your work so we can follow your line of reasoning. For the first one, I would replace $x-u=\int _u^xdt$ and then change the order of integration

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for the first case:** $\displaystyle g(x) = \int_0^x (x-u) e^{u^2}\, du$

You may write $\displaystyle g(x) = x\cdot \int_0^x e^{u^2}\, du- \int_0^x u e^{u^2}\, du$. Then, you may apply the chain rule and the following one:
$$\boxed{F(x) = \displaystyle \int_a^{g(x)}f(u)\, du \implies F'(x) = f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x).}$$

Thus, $g'(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x e^{u^2}\, du + x\cdot e^{x^2} - x\cdot e^{x^2} = \int_0^{x} e^{u^2}\, du $.

I think you can take it from here.

---

Similarly, you can handle the case $\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$.

**Hint for the case $\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}$**:

Firstly, you can compute the integral $\displaystyle \int_1^x e^{ty}\,dt = \int_1^x (e^y)^t\, dt$, taking for granted that $\displaystyle \int a^t\, dt = \dfrac{a^t}{\ln a}+c$.

Thus, $\psi(x,y) = \displaystyle \int_1^x  (e^y)^t \, dt = \cdots = \dfrac{e^{xy}-e^y}{y}$.

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you friend, it makes more sense now

Comment: @Bob You are welcome.